# A Laravel test that requires authentication does not pass in GitHub action

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-livewire

I have a simple test that checks that the dashboard is renderable for authenticated users.

Here is the code:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Tests\TestCase;

class DashboardTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_dashboard_page_can_be_rendered()
    {
        $this->actingAs(User::factory()->create());

        $response = $this->get('/dashboard');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

This code works fine when I run `php artisan test`.

Output:

```bash
PASS  Tests\Feature\DashboardTest
  ✓ dashboard page can be rendered
```

But, when running this on GitHub Actions, I get the following error:

```bash
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\DashboardTest::test_dashboard_page_can_be_rendered
Expected response status code [200] but received 302.
Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 302.

/home/runner/work/material-hub/material-hub/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Testing/TestResponse.php:198
/home/runner/work/material-hub/material-hub/tests/Feature/DashboardTest.php:17
```

Comment: Looks like it is being redirected, so the User is not being used in the `actingAs`, try to check if the user is set or stored before you execute `->get`

Comment: In my local everything works fine.

Comment: I know it works in local, I am talking about GitHub Actions. Try adding a `dump` or something after the `actingAs` but store the user in a variable, and `dump` that variable to see if it has a model or a boolean (meaning it was not able to store it in GitHub Actions)

Comment: I have checked, The user is getting stored in the variable.

Comment: Then what I have in mind is that you have something set on your `.env` that is changing your default config, and when you run it on GitHub Actions, you truly have the default + the overrides from `phpunit.xml`, check that please

Comment: I can confirm that it's not overriding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252722/discussion-between-dasun-tharanga-and-matiaslauriti).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed passing a middleware that I used to group all routes. It must be passed otherwise redirect will occur as described error.

That middleware is passed now and all tests run as usual.

Answer (score 0):

302 means that you are redirected to another page. I would assume that the reason this happens is that the user you are creating is not used or authenticated to go to the requested route.

You can try a similar approach by twisting your code a bit:

```
   $user = User::factory()->create();
   $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/dashboard');

   $response->assertStatus(200);
```

That way you ensure that the user you have created will be the one to access the route you want.

In the `actingAs` you can also use a second parameter to define specifically the guard you want to use for authentication, for example:

```
$this->actingAs($user, 'your_guard')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. I have passed the 2nd argument already.